# About ROSA (Red Hat OpenShift Service on AWS) cloudwatch monitoring

Tags: openshift, amazon-cloudwatch, redhat

What can I see from cloudwatch with ROSA(Red Hat OpenShift Service on AWS)  log transfers?
CPU usage, memory usage, disk usage, etc.
process monitoring
Can I forward specific logs?
Can I see all of these in cloudwatch?

I've searched all over and can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log forwarding with ROSA sends 3 log groups..

1. kubernetes audit and openshift audit
2. infrastructure (cluster operators, system journal logs, pod logs for all OpenShift components like etcd, ovn, SRE, machine api, kube apiserver, prometheus logs, openshift-ingress, etc)
3. user workload logs (from app workloads that run on worker nodes)

You generally send everything from a ROSA cluster to Cloudwatch Logs and then filter after that.

Resource metrics are not in logs, but instead in the in-cluster Prometheus. Matrics are also retrieved by Cloudwatch Metrics for all of the EC2 and EBS resources.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to install the cloudwatch agent in the master EC2, infrastructure EC2, and worker EC2 and monitor them?